Performance of std::mdspan vs boost::multi_array
If I understand correctly, the basic difference between these two is that mdspan is just a view into an existing storage but multi_array creates and manages the storage itself.
My question is whether this storage management brings a significant overhead when

deep copying the multi-dimensional array
accessing elements of the array

The array won't be resized so the speed/complexity of resizing is not important now.

The best way to find out is to create a program that uses both libraries in the way you want to use them and benchmark it

Talking about performance without doing actual measurement can be quite misleading. So, I would recommend write some performance tests and do some experiments.

whether overhead is significant or not depends on your actual use case. What is negligible in one case might be significant in another case. The only way to know is to measure
